# Trying to implement excanvas but getting errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, excanvas

I'm trying to implement excanvas so that my script works in IE as well as standards compliant browsers.  I'm including jquery, excanvas then my script. I'm creating the canvas element like so:

```
data.canvas = $(document.createElement('canvas')).attr('width', data.fontwidth * 80 + 'px').attr('height', data.fontheight * 25 + 'px');
$this.append(data.canvas);
```

But when I try `ctx = data.canvas[0].getContext('2d');` I'm getting an `Object doesn't support this property or method' error on that line. Additionally I'm getting an`Invalid argument` error on line 160 inside excanvas.js.

My full code is [here](http://justinzaun.com/ansi/js/ansi.js). The working (in everything except IE) page is [here](http://justinzaun.com/ansi). The version of excanvas I'm using is [here](http://explorercanvas.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/excanvas.js).

**update** solved the 2nd error. i had to append the element before calling the init function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/wiki/Instructions):

> If you have created your canvas
>   element dynamically it will not have
>   the getContext method added to the
>   element. To get it working you need to
>   call initElement on the
>   G_vmlCanvasManager object.

```
var el = document.createElement('canvas');
G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(el);
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
```

Comment: This solves the 1st error, not the second. I'm still getting the `Invalid argument` error on line 160 in excanvas.js script.

Answer (score 1):

canvas width attribute must be number.

```
<canvas width="164" height="164"></canvas>
```

not

```
<canvas width="164px" height="164px"></canvas>
```